# How do I get an Arduino to communicate back to LabVIEW in real time?

Tags: arduino, labview

I am trying to run a program where the Arduino will send data to LabVIEW. LabVIEW should then get said data and work with it. Is there a standard or method I can use?
PS. All of this has to be done in real time, i.e., I don't want to send data to my computer, save it on a file and then have LabVIEW access it.

Comment: It's pretty easy to talk to an Arduino in lab view (or any language) as a USB serial port. You open the port, send your text and then read the response. It is slow though.